# How to avoid hardcoding when filtering lists based on sublists?

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of lists, and I am dropping all lists that do not contain `sl[0]` or `sl[1]` sub-lists:

```
l = [
 ['s1', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's15', 's23'],
 ['s1', 's5', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's15', 's23'],
 ['s1', 's5', 's6', 's10', 's14', 's15', 's23']
]
sl = [['s5','s6','s8'],['s15', 's23']]
```

This code is hardcoded for 2 sub-lists `sl[0]` and `sl[1]`:

```
list(filter(lambda l : not(set(sl[0]+sl[1])-set(l)), l))
```

How can I make this code more flexible? What if `sl` contains 5 or 10 or any other number of sub-lists?

Comment: You want to remove lists from `l` that do not contain either of the ordered sequences contained in `sl`, or that do not contain all of the element in either of the lists in `sl`?

Comment: @James: I want to remove lists from `l` that do not contain the ordered sequences contained in `sl`.

Comment: And what do you mean by flexible ? The question from James is important as your answer will influence the complexity of the algorithm you need

Comment: @VictorDeleau: The "flexibility" refers to a non-hardcoded approach. Currently I specify `sl[0]+sl[1]`, but what if `sl` contains hundreds of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `more-itertools` package.  You will need to check each of the subsequences of `len(sl[i])` in each of the elements of `l`.  It will be slow, but doable.

I also created a factory function that uses `partial` so you can just pop in whatever your `sl` happens to be.  This keeps with your use of `filter`.

```py
from more_itertools import windowed
from functools import partial

def ordered_check(x, sub):
    s = tuple(sub)
    for y in windowed(x, len(sub)):
        if s == y:
            return True
    return False

def ordered_check_all(x, subs):
    return all(ordered_check(x, sub) for sub in subs)

def check_factory(subs):
    return partial(ordered_check_all, subs=subs)

list(filter(check_factory(sl), l))
# returns
[['s1', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's15', 's23'],
 ['s1', 's5', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's15', 's23'],
 ['s1', 's5', 's6', 's10', 's14', 's15', 's23']]
```

Comment: Why `['s1', 's5', 's6', 's10', 's14', 's15', 's23']` is returned? It does not contain the sub-list `['s5','s6','s8']`. To fit my requirements, I substituted `any(ordered_check(x, sub) for sub in subs)` by `all(ordered_check(x, sub) for sub in subs)`. Can you update your answer, so that I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: It is returned because it contains the sequence `['s15', 's23']`.  I may have misunderstood the question.  Do you need all of the subsequences to be present?  If so, indeed, `all` is the correct method.  I have updated accordingly

Comment: A quick clarification: do you know how to filter lists that do NOT contain any of sub-lists? I tried to use `list(filter(~check_factory(sl), l))`. If there is a quick solution, I'd appreciate your hint. Otherwise, I will open a new thread. Thanks.

Comment: You can wrap it in a lambda function.  `list(filter(lambda x: not check_factory(sl)(x), l))`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very hard time reading your code:

```
list(filter(lambda l : not(set(sl[0]+sl[1])-set(l)), l))
```

First you concatenate `s1[0]` and `sl[1]`:

```
['s5','s6','s8'] + ['s15', 's23']
becomes
['s5','s6','s8', 's15', 's23']
```

Then you make a set from `sl[0]+sl[1]` ....`set(sl[0]+sl[1])`:

```
{'s5','s6','s8', 's15', 's23'}
```

Then you subtract `set(l)` from that result. That won't even work, because `l` is a list of lists. A list of strings can be converted into a set because elements of a set can be strings. However, lists cannot be elements of a set.

---

Comment: Thanks, but what is your answer?